# Using PIL on online-python.com

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to run the following code on python-online.com

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.new('RGB', (600,600))
pixels = img.load()
for x in range(0,300):
    for y in range(0,300):
        pixels[x,y] = (255,0,0)
for x in range(300,600):
    for y in range(0,300):
        pixels[x,y] = (0,255,0)
for x in range(0,300):
    for y in range(300,600):
        pixels[x,y] = (0,0,255)
img.save('test.png')
```

When I run it, I receive the error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'PIL'
```

I understand that if I use another compiler, I can get around this problem, but I would like to know if there is someone to use PIL on python-online.com that doesn't involve downloading anything.

I have tried commands like "pip install Pillow" but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: It seems that the `online-python.com` interpreter doesn't even have internet access, so I don't think you can install PIL there. Have you tried Python Anywhere?

Comment: Try here https://ideone.com/ It seems to allow importing and using PIL.

Comment: Using `for` loops like that is pretty horrible, by the way. You can draw three rectangles like that much faster with `Image.paste()`. Or with `ImageDraw.rectangle()`. Or use Numpy slicing. Or create a 2x2 image in the 4 colours and use `Image.resize()`.

Answer (score 2):

I got the code to work on Replit.com. Thanks for your encouragement to try other platforms!